# Star graph and cayley’s theorem

Tags: algorithm, tree

I was given the following q.:
*An undirected (K,L)-star is a tree T = (V, E), with  ∗  vertices with degree 1,  vertices with degree ( + 1) and 1 vertex with degree . What is the form of the 
word, created by Cayley’s theorem, that is associated with a (K, L)-star?*

I got that T={|V|=LK+L+1, |E|=KL+L} but I don't really know how to continue from here. I know that for this tree there are (KL+L)^(KL+L-2) options for creating a word but can I have more assumptions on the words that will be created?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what can I tell about the word:
first, it's length is |V|-2=LK+L+1-2=LK+L-1 and second each letter appears deg(v)-1 times in the word. Therefore, there are L letters K times and 1 letter appears L-1 times in the word